# REST WCF authentication scheme

Tags: iis, authentication, rest

How do I change my REST service (Factory?) to allow it to work on IIS? I can not change IIS.

I get this error:

IIS specified authentication schemes 'IntegratedWindowsAuthentication, Anonymous', but the binding only supports specification of exactly one authentication scheme. Valid authentication schemes are Digest, Negotiate, NTLM, Basic, or Anonymous. Change the IIS settings so that only a single authentication scheme is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not appear to be a way. Multiple authentication must be taken off the site via IIS.